# Does delegatecall also works for calling other contract's constructor?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, contract-debugging, delegatecall

I want to call other contract's constructor, but I'm not sure if the delegatecall function will work for that case. I have no way to test it out on Remix, because my Remix seem to not work with even simple contracts that use the delegatecall function :/

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Since the constructor is only once used when you deploy a smart contract **there is no way to use delegatecall** for it. If you can explain why you want to do something like this maybe I can help with more info.

Comment: Unless they are using an upgradeable contract and they're trying to call the initializer function... But of course that is not a constructor